# How to capture return variable value when pipeline is executed from REST API call in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

[As of 2023](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-return-value), we can now capture an output from a child pipeline executed from a parent pipeline.

Is it possible to capture this value when the pipeline was executed via the `Web Activity` REST API call? Meaning, making a `GET` call on that child pipeline from the parent one (not executed with `Execute Pipeline Activity`) will return the return variable in the Web activity JSON body output?

I'm trying to make my Data Factory completely meta-data driven but I always end up making switches to run different copy activities at the lowest level, which works, but it is limited to 25 switches (sources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to capture this value when the pipeline was executed via the `Web Activity` REST API call?

[`Pipelines - Create Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/create-run?view=rest-datafactory-2018-06-01&tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0) REST API won't capture the return values by the child pipeline. Its only job is to create the pipeline run for the given pipeline and it will only return that pipeline `runId` as output.

[image]

To capture the output of the pipeline, you can use [`Pipeline Runs - Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/get?view=rest-datafactory-2018-06-01&tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) REST API after the above web activity. Use another web activity and pass the `runId` from the above activity. Give the **URL** expression like below in the second web activity.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<RG_name>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<DataFactory_name>/pipelineruns/@{activity('Web1').output.runId}?api-version=2018-06-01
```

[image]

This will give the Child pipeline returned output in its response.

[image]

To get these values, use this expression `@activity('Web1').output.pipelineReturnValue.<return1 or return2>` in your next activities.

**But you need to consider below things in this approach:**

- Here, the second web activity will execute right after the first one and it will not return the return value if the child pipeline run is not completed.
- It means, **it won't wait till the completion of the pipeline run**, If the pipeline is still in progress, it will give the same information and **return values as null** like below.

  [image]
- To avoid this, you need to add a **wait activity** before the second web activity and give certain amount of time in seconds which your child pipeline will take to complete its run. (Or) **you can try like below if you don't know the pipeline duration**.

  ```
  -Web1 activity
  - Set a flag variable to false
  - Use until activity(condition - flag==true)
          - web activity to check the status of the pipeline run.
          - Update flag to true if pipeline run completed
  - Web activity to capture the child pipeline output
  ```

So, if your pipelines are in same ADF, then it's better to use Execute pipeline activity to do this. Because a single **Execute pipeline activity does all the above approach** and can capture the output as well.

[image]

Comment: I like this answer! Thank you. I now know that the executed pipeline returns the return variable in the json response body of the GET call.

Comment: The reason I asked was because I wanted to execute several different pipelines dynamically. The only way to achieve this is by using the API as far as I know, however, then we need to do the steps you presented above PLUS we are limited to only execute pipelines that are published, and the names of the pipelines cannot change. Otherwise we are left with one/many switch(es).